# Adding values in my database via a ManyToMany relationship represented in admin.py

Tags: django, django-admin, manytomanyfield

I've got a tiny little problem that, unfortunately, is taking all my time.

It is really simple, I already have my database and I created then modified models.py, and admin.py. Some staff users, who will need to enter values in my database, need the simpliest form to do so.

Here is my database :

---

-- Table `NGSdb`.`line`

---

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NGSdb`.`line` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `value` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `value_UNIQUE` ON `NGSdb`.`line` (`value` ASC) ;
```

---

-- Table `NGSdb`.`run_has_sample_lines`

---

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NGSdb`.`run_has_sample_lines` (
  `line_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `runhassample_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`line_id`, `runhassample_id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sample_has_line_line1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`line_id` )
    REFERENCES `NGSdb`.`line` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sample_has_line_run_has_sample1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`runhassample_id` )
    REFERENCES `NGSdb`.`run_has_sample` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

---

-- Table `NGSdb`.`run_has_sample`

---

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NGSdb`.`run_has_sample` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `run_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `sample_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `dna_quantification_ng_per_ul` FLOAT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `run_id`, `sample_id`) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_run_has_sample_run1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`run_id` )
    REFERENCES `NGSdb`.`run` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_run_has_sample_sample1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sample_id` )
    REFERENCES `NGSdb`.`sample` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Here is my models.py :

```
class Run(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)   
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='start date')
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='end date')
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    sequencing_type = models.ForeignKey(SequencingType)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"run started %s from the project %s" % (self.start_date,self.project)


class Line(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    value = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % str(self.value)


class RunHasSample(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
run = models.ForeignKey(Run)
sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample)
dna_quantification_ng_per_ul = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
lines = models.ManyToManyField(Line)
def __unicode__(self):
    return u"Sample %s from run %s" % (self.sample, self.run)
```

And here is my admin.py :

```
class RunHasSamplesInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = RunHasSample
    fields = ['sample', 'dna_quantification_ng_per_ul', 'lines']    
    extra = 6

class RunAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['project', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'sequencing_type']
    inlines = [RunHasSamplesInLine]
    list_display = ('project', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'sequencing_type')
```

As you can see, my samples are displayed in lines in the run form so that the staff can easily fullfill the database.
When I try to fill the database I have this error :

> (1054, "Unknown column 'run_has_sample_lines.id' in 'field list'")

Of course, there are no field "lines" in my database ! It is a many to many field so I already created my intermediate table !

Okay okay ! So I tried to create the model for the intermediate table (run_has_sample_lines) and add a "through" to the ManyToManyField in the RunHasSample model. But, as I add manually the "through", I cannot use the ManyToMany field. The only way to add lines to the admin view is to stack them in lines... As you can see the samples are already in lines, it is impossible to put a new "inlines" in the already in lines samples...

Finally, I just tried to see what django had created with the manage.py sqlall. 
I see that :

```
 CREATE TABLE `run_has_sample_lines` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `runhassample_id` integer NOT NULL,
    `line_id` integer NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (`runhassample_id`, `line_id`)
)
;
ALTER TABLE `run_has_sample_lines` ADD CONSTRAINT `line_id_refs_id_4f0766aa` FOREIGN KEY (`line_id`) REFERENCES `line` (`id`);
```

It seems that there are no foreign key on the run_has_sample table whereas I created it in the database in the first place. I guess that the problem is coming from here but I cannot resolve it and I really hope that you can...

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

you may wish to try a 'through' attribute on the many-to-many relationship and declare your intermediate table in Django.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I didn't find a way to use a ManyToManyField in the admin.py interface when we use the "through". Here is my error "Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value: 
'RunHasSamplesInLine.fields' can't include the ManyToManyField field 'lines' because 'lines' manually specifies a 'through' model.

Answer (score 0):

I found where the problem is...

It is not a problem in the ManyToManyField but in the intermediate table. Django refused that my intermediate table doesn't have an unique id !

So, in the sql which created django, it created automatically an unique id named "id", but in my database I didn't create one (because the couple of two foreign key is usually enough).

Next time, I'll be more carefull.